# NaN values while computing the probability in binomial distribution

Tags: r

I would like to compute integrate the following function

```
riskFunction <- function(theta, n, r, s)
    {
        risk <- 0
        for (j in 1:n)
            {
               risk <- risk + abs(theta - r * j - s) * dbinom(j, n, theta)
            }
        return(risk)
    }
```

using the trapeizodal method on the interval [0, 1]. That's my code

```
trapeizodalMethod <- function(a, b, m, n, r, s)
{
  intValue <- 0
  h <- (b - a)/m
  for (i in 0:m-1)
  {
    intValue <- intValue + 0.5 * (riskFunction(a + i * h, n=n, r=r, s=s) + riskFunction(a + (i + 1) * h, n=n, r=r, s=s)) * h
  }
  return(intValue)
}
```

After calling *trapezoidalMethod*

```
trapeizodalMethod(a=0, b=1, m=100, n=100, r=0.01, s=0)
```

more than 50 errors occurs: **In dbinom(j, 100, theta) : NaN produced**.

I have no idea what might have gone wrong. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: Your code is incomplete:  you haven't shown us what arguments you passed to `trapeizodalMethod`.  But in any case, the `riskFunction` code looks wrong:  it calculates `risk` for lots of values of `j` but only saves the last one, and doesn't have any return value.

Comment: @user2554330 I'm sorry I fixed those mistakes. However they were only typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning arises when `dbinom(x, size, prob, log = FALSE)` has `prob` outside `[0, 1]`. In your case, `theta = -0.01` occurs because the loop is not running as you expected.

The binary operator `:` has higher precedence than binary `-`. So for example `1:5-1` is evaluated as `(1:5) - 1`, not `1:(5 - 1)`. You want

```
trapeizodalMethod <- function(a, b, m, n, r, s)
{
  intValue <- 0
  h <- (b - a)/m
  for (i in 0:(m-1)) {
            # ^^^^^  
    intValue <- intValue + 0.5 * (riskFunction(a + i * h, n=n, r=r, s=s) + riskFunction(a + (i + 1) * h, n=n, r=r, s=s)) * h
  }
  return(intValue)
}
```